# UDP передача файла, в формате "вопрос - ответ"

Tags: python, udp

Хочу организовать UDP передачу в формате "вопрос-ответ". Но первое же сообщение не проходит (первый файл отсылает, но второй не принимает). При этом же, если убрать пересылку второго сообщения, первое магическим образом начинает работать.

Первый файл

```
import socket
import struct

##########################################################  Клиент
UDP_send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host_send = "127.0.0.1"
port_send = 25001
addr_send = (host_send, port_send)
##########################################################  Сервер
UDP_rsv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host_rsv = "127.0.0.1"
port_rsv = 25002
addr_rsv = (host_rsv, port_rsv)
UDP_rsv.bind(addr_rsv)
UDP_rsv.settimeout(15)


while True:
    s = 1212.25544
    data_send = struct.pack('d', s)
    UDP_send.sendto(data_send, addr_send)
    # получение ответа
    try:
        pr_rsv_ansvr = UDP_rsv.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
    pr_rsv_ansvr = struct.unpack('d', pr_rsv_ansvr)
```

Второй файл

```
import socket
import struct

##########################################################  Клиент
UDP_send = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host_send = "127.0.0.1"
port_send = 25002
addr_send = (host_send, port_send)
##########################################################  Сервер
UDP_rsv = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host_rsv = "127.0.0.1"
port_rsv = 25001
addr_rsv = (host_rsv, port_rsv)
UDP_rsv.bind(addr_rsv)
UDP_rsv.settimeout(15)

while True:
    try:
        data_rsv, addr = UDP_rsv.recvfrom(1024)
    except socket.timeout:
        pass
    key = struct.unpack('d', data_rsv)
    # send ansvr
    pr_send_ansvr = struct.pack('d', 1010.1010)
    UDP_send.sendto(pr_send_ansvr, addr_send)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В блоке `except` нужно передавать тип ошибки, а не просто переменную, например `Exception`. Но в данном случае можно реализовать передачу и без него, так как цикл не перейдёт к следующей итерации, пока не примет сообщение. Вот пример рабочего кода (сначала запускается 2.py, потом 1.py):

1.py

```
import socket
import struct

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
addr_send = ("127.0.0.1", 25000)

addr_rsv = ("127.0.0.1", 25001)
socket.bind(addr_rsv)
socket.settimeout(15)

for i in xrange(100000):
    data_send = struct.pack('i', i)
    socket.sendto(data_send, addr_send)

    data_rsv, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024)
    data_rsv = struct.unpack('i', data_rsv)
    print(data_rsv[0]
```

2.py

```
import socket
import struct

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
addr_send = ("127.0.0.1", 25001)

addr_rsv = ("127.0.0.1", 25000)
socket.bind(addr_rsv)
socket.settimeout(15)

for i in xrange(100000):
    data_rsv, addr = socket.recvfrom(1024)
    data_rsv = struct.unpack('i', data_rsv)

    data_send = struct.pack('i', data_rsv[0])
    socket.sendto(data_send, addr_send)
    print(data_rsv[0])
```